# Resolvent is continuous

Tags: operator-theory

I try to show that the resolvent of an operator (unbounded) $T$ on Hilbert space is a continuous function of the complex variable.
For that I derived the following:

$R(z)-R(a)=-(z-a)R(z)R(a)$, where $z$ is in a neighborhood of $a$ inside the resolvent set and $R(z):=(z-T)^{-1}$

So I'd like to conclude that $R$ is continuous in $a$ but the $R(z)$ on the right-hand side of the equation troubles me.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Methinks you have a sign error. Apart from that, can you show that $\lVert R(z)\rVert$ is bounded near $a$?

Comment: True I correct the error now. Yeah that's the point: how to prove that? I guess a contradiction argument...but I'm not sure how.

Comment: This works because the resolvent set of an operator is always open. This in turn follows from the fact that small perturbations of invertible operators are invertible. Usually this proved by some variant of the Neumann series.